# Can I add two wordpress shortcode plugins in the same site (not the same page)?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

Is there a problem with defining the same subdirectory structure for two or more WordPress plugins ? I have the following structure for my two plugins :

[image]

Then in a wordpress page I insert the first plugin (skiamap_states) and no problem.

But if I insert the second shortcode plugin (skiamap_usa_capitals) in another page without the first one, and if I check the sources in the browser (CTRL + SHIFT + I) then I find the following subdirectories structure :

[image]

That is to say, WordPress mixed the subdirectories of the first plugin (which works perfectly in another page) with one subdirectory of the second plugin, and this last one is the one inserted at that page, not the first one...As a result, the javascript code is searching for images references that are not found because that subdirectory was not included.

If I deactivate de first plugin, then this page with the second plugin works correctly.

What is the problem ?

EDIT:

I added the plugin code...sorry this is very basic plugin because I am very new to PHP and to develop plugins for WordPress.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: SkiaMap for layer {layername}
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.org/plugins/skiamap/
 * Description: A plugin for layer {layername} creating a Leaflet map with a shortcode and to play animations instead of a popup. 
 * Author: Advantrix
 * Author URI: https://www.skiamap.com/
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * License: Commercial
 */
// activar y desactivar plugin

// Activar el plugin
function skiamap_activar_{layername}() {
    // Agregar acciones o configuraciones de activación aquí
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'skiamap_activar_{layername}');

// Desactivar el plugin
function skiamap_desactivar_{layername}() {
    // Agregar acciones o configuraciones de desactivación aquí
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'skiamap_desactivar_{layername}');

// Eliminar el plugin
function skiamap_eliminar_{layername}() {
    // Agregar acciones o configuraciones de eliminación aquí
}
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'skiamap_eliminar_{layername}');

// enqueue leaflet and skiamap scripts

function skiamap_enqueue_scripts_{layername}() {
    wp_enqueue_script('leaflet', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js', array(), '1.9.4', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('canvas-txt', 'https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt', array(), '4.0.4', true);
    // Enqueue additional JavaScript files
    //wp_enqueue_script('show-popup', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/custom-popup.js', array('jquery', 'leaflet'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('clipper', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/Doodle3D/clipper.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('skiamaplib', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/webanimator/skiamaplib.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('animator', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/anim/animator.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('openmap', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/openmap.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);

    wp_enqueue_style('popup-dialog', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'styles/popup-dialog.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('leaflet', 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css', array(), '1.9.4');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'skiamap_enqueue_scripts_{layername}');

// create a ShortCode for the map

function render_skiamap_{layername}($atts, $content, $tag) {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering

    // Shortcode attributes
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'maptype' => 'osm',
        'mapboxid' => 'mapbox.satellite',
        'apikey' => 'xxyy',
        'width' => '100%',
        'height' => '500',
        'markercolor' => 'blue',
    ), $atts);

        $map_id = esc_attr('skmap' . uniqid());
        $dialog_id = esc_attr('skdialog' . uniqid());
        $button_id = esc_attr('skbuttontoggle' . uniqid());
        $canvas_id = esc_attr('skcanvas' . uniqid());
        //$buttonClick_id = esc_attr('buttonClick' . uniqid());

        //$markerIconUrl = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/marker_red.png';

        $mapwidth = $a['width'];
        $endsWithPercent = '%';
        $endsWithPixel = 'px';
        if (substr($mapwidth, -strlen($endsWithPercent)) === $endsWithPercent) {
        }
        elseif (substr($mapwidth, -strlen($endsWithPixel)) === $endsWithPixel) {
        }
        else {
            // se assume pixels
            $mapwidth .= "px";
        }

        $mapheight = $a['height'];
        if (substr($mapheight, -strlen($endsWithPercent)) === $endsWithPercent) {
        }
        elseif (substr($mapheight, -strlen($endsWithPixel)) === $endsWithPixel) {
        }
        else {
            // se assume pixels
            $mapheight .= "px";
        }
    ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $map_id; ?>" style="width: <?php echo $mapwidth; ?>; height: <?php echo $mapheight; ?>;"></div>
    <!--div id="skmap" style="width:100%; height:500px; border:solid black 1px;"></div-->
    
    <dialog id="<?php echo $dialog_id; ?>" style="border: 2px solid black;">
        <div>   
            <button onclick="skiaMapSettings.skButtonClick(1)" title="Play Again"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/play16.png'; ?>" alt="Play Again" /></button>
            <button onclick="skiaMapSettings.skButtonClick(2)" title="Previous Page"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/previous16.png'; ?>" alt="Previous Page" /></button>
            <button onclick="skiaMapSettings.skButtonClick(3)" title="Next Page"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/next16.png'; ?>" alt="Next Page" /></button>
            <button onclick="skiaMapSettings.skButtonClick(5)" title="Close"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/close16.png'; ?>" alt="Close" /></button>
            <button id="<?php echo $button_id; ?>" hidden onclick="skiaMapSettings.skButtonClick(6)" title="Toggle elements in Carousel"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/special/exchange16.png'; ?>"  alt="Toggle elements in carousel" /></button>
        </div>
        <canvas id="<?php echo $canvas_id; ?>" width="100" height="100" style="solid black 1px"></canvas>
    </dialog>

    <input type="hidden" id="__skplugindirurl__" name="__skplugindirurl__" 
        value="<?php echo $map_id; ?>;<?php echo $dialog_id; ?>;<?php echo $button_id; ?>;<?php echo $canvas_id; ?>;<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>;<?php echo $a['maptype']; ?>;<?php echo $a['mapboxid']; ?>;<?php echo $a['apikey']; ?>;<?php echo $a['markercolor']; ?>" />

<?php

    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content
}

add_shortcode('{shortcodename}', 'render_skiamap_{layername}');

?>
```

This code has key codes like {shortcodename} and {layername} because a desktop application replaces those codes by the name of the plugin and the layer generated from a GIS application.

Comment: There's no reason you can't do this. Did you develop these plugins? If not you'll need to speak to its author. If you did you'll need to share the code you're using to include images.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I developed the pluggin...I added the code if that can be helpful to solve this issue...

Comment: I can send the two plugins if someone is interested in checking...please...